# Unable to send and recieve data in HINDI language from NOKIA S40 series cell phone correctly

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, nokia-s40, hindi

I am trying to send data in HINDI language using JAXRPC webservice from my NOKIA S40 Series Cell phone, The main issue is that the data recieved on the webserver is not in correct format. All I get on the webserver is "?????" (question marks). Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode your Strings to UTF-8 on device before sending to webservice. Make sure to decode from UTF-8 when receiving it in webservice.

Comment: Telmo Pimentel Mota I tried but Don't have enough reputation to accept your answer :(

Comment: When you do, remember to visit your questions and accept the answers.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using inputstream then get it like below code

```
 HttpConnection conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(Feed);
    InputStream rssStream = conn.openInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(rssStream, "utf8");
```